# how to save dynamically added div in another html file?

Tags: jquery

I added a dynamic div. I want to open in another HTML page when I update div and refresh another HTML page then it added updated div.

```js
$(".save").click(function() {
  $("#drag-right-2").load("demo-6-content.html");
});
```

I tried this but it is not working:

```
$(".save").click(function() {
  $("#drag-right-2").load("demo-6-content.html");
});
```

First I add column dynamic then after I drag and drop an item from the left sidebar in column I want save button click to save dynamic add column and drop item in column open in new HTML page.

Comment: Looks like you need server-side work, at the very least for filesystem write operations. _(would be a good idea to also add layers like access rights, edition semaphore, etc.)_